# Error on reopening files from previous session via desktop-save-mode

Tags: start-up, session

I like my Emacs to reopen all previously opened files when I start it up.

My setup is simple:

```
;; save desktop autosave sessions
(setq desktop-dirname             "~/"
      desktop-base-file-name      ".emacs.desktop"
      desktop-base-lock-name      "lock"
      desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
      desktop-save                t
      desktop-files-not-to-save   "^$" ;reload tramp paths
      desktop-load-locked-desktop nil)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(setq desktop-restore-frames t)
(setq desktop-restore-in-current-display t)
(setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)

;; measured in autosave cycles
(setq desktop-recover-save-period 1)

;; ; if idle s save
(run-with-idle-timer 60.0 t 'desktop-save-in-desktop-dir)
```

The problem is that after startup, the .emacs.desktop file is not reloaded - the only thing reopened is the buffer that was active when I quit emacs.

The .emacs.desktop was correctly saved in the previous session (every 60s of idle time as per my setup) and the file looks ok to me... I can't reload it with `desktop-read` either I get this error:

> desktop-create-buffer: Wrong number of arguments: #[(beg end length)
>   "è         è Æ=MÇ È!.GÉV.ÊË!.ËÉH!?IÌÍ#Æ=I
>   ÉUI67ZÎU)Y89zÏ)e Ð=e Ñ=¦7eVè7SfzÏèÒvÓ
>   :Ô`;ÕÖxÉW²×Ø!ÉW²`<Ö=>ÞÖ?;bÙÚÛÜ>Ý#ÞQ!)ÞÎÎ{=>?£ß
>   àá=>âÜãä&Í#£?*)£Ö?;bÙë!)£Í=ìíîÉÉ{\"!ïð!£ß
>   ;bñÎ!.Eè ò=½ ÉUè Í=è7bÓ
>   :óôõ6Í#çÆÉfF8ÀÉÉÉ#+È+" [auto-capitalize
>   auto-capitalize-predicate this-command key global-map length
>   self-insert-command this-command-keys vectorp 0 ...] 9
>   ("/home/rxs/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-capitalize-20131013.2205/auto-capitalize.elc"
>   . 3420)], 1 desktop-create-buffer: Wrong number of arguments: #[(beg
>   end length) "è         è Æ=MÇ
>   È!.GÉV.ÊË!.ËÉH!?IÌÍ#Æ=I ÉUI67ZÎU)Y89zÏ)e
>   Ð=e Ñ=¦7eVè7SfzÏèÒvÓ
>   :Ô`;ÕÖxÉW²×Ø!ÉW²`<Ö=>ÞÖ?;bÙÚÛÜ>Ý#ÞQ!)ÞÎÎ{=>?£ß
>   àá=>âÜãä&Í#£?*)£Ö?;bÙë!)£Í=ìíîÉÉ{\"!ïð!£ß
>   ;bñÎ!.Eè ò=½ ÉUè Í=è7bÓ
>   :óôõ6Í#çÆÉfF8ÀÉÉÉ#+È+" [auto-capitalize
>   auto-capitalize-predicate this-command key global-map length
>   self-insert-command this-command-keys vectorp 0 ...] 9
>   ("/home/rxs/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-capitalize-20131013.2205/auto-capitalize.elc"
>   . 3420)], 1

My .emacs.desktop file:

```
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; coding: emacs-mule; -*-
;; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Desktop File for Emacs
;; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Created Thu Jan 21 11:26:04 2016
;; Desktop file format version 206
;; Emacs version 24.5.1

;; Global section:
(setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (22176 45628 743516 309000) (desktop . "206") "rxs@localhost.localdomain" nil nil ((((font-backend xft x) (font . "-unknown-Liberation Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1") (font-parameter) (border-width . 0) (internal-border-width . 1) (right-divider-width . 0) (bottom-divider-width . 0) (vertical-scroll-bars) (foreground-color . "#f8f8f8") (background-color . "#26292c") (mouse-color . "black") (border-color . "black") (screen-gamma) (line-spacing) (left-fringe . 10) (right-fringe . 11) (scroll-bar-foreground) (scroll-bar-background . "grey75") (menu-bar-lines . 0) (tool-bar-lines . 0) (title) (wait-for-wm . t) (fullscreen) (tool-bar-position . top) (icon-type . t) (auto-raise) (auto-lower) (cursor-type . box) (scroll-bar-width . 0) (alpha) (horizontal-scroll-bars . t) (display-type . color) (background-mode . dark) (cursor-color . "brown3") (environment) (powerline-cache) (frameset--id . "1A06-6A10-F26F-68FD") (frameset--mini t . t) (height . 55) (width . 179) (modeline . t) (minibuffer . t) (unsplittable) (left . 0) (top . 0) (icon-name) (visibility . t) (display . ":0") (explicit-name)) ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 2) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 56) (min-pixel-width . 70) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 28) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 35) (min-pixel-height-safe . 14) (min-pixel-width-safe . 14)) leaf (pixel-width . 1276) (pixel-height . 762) (total-width . 182) (total-height . 54) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "org-wiki.org" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 11 nil) (margins 3) (scroll-bars 0 0 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 24576) (start . 1))))])
(setq desktop-missing-file-warning nil)
(setq tags-file-name nil)
(setq tags-table-list nil)
(setq search-ring '("ohio" "q" "someb" "revie" "exp" "grow" "goals" "make" "agile"))
(setq regexp-search-ring nil)
(setq register-alist '((48 . "")))
(setq file-name-history '("/home/rxs/org/wiki/org-wiki.org" "/home/rxs/org/agenda.org" "/home/rxs/.emacs.desktop"))

;; Buffer section -- buffers listed in same order as in buffer list:
(desktop-create-buffer 206
  "/home/rxs/org/wiki/org-wiki.org"
  "org-wiki.org"
  'org-mode
  '(rsk-minor-mode override-global-mode auto-compile-on-load-mode auto-capitalize which-key-mode beacon-mode modalka-mode helm-mode company-mode ivy-mode yas-minor-mode smartparens-mode)
  24576
  '(nil nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix) (truncate-lines . t)))

(desktop-create-buffer 206
  "/home/rxs/org/agenda.org"
  "agenda.org"
  'org-mode
  '(rsk-minor-mode override-global-mode auto-compile-on-load-mode auto-capitalize which-key-mode beacon-mode modalka-mode helm-mode company-mode ivy-mode yas-minor-mode smartparens-mode)
  1
  '(nil nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix) (truncate-lines . t)))

(desktop-create-buffer 206
  "/home/rxs/.emacs.desktop"
  ".emacs.desktop"
  'emacs-lisp-mode
  '(rsk-minor-mode override-global-mode auto-compile-on-load-mode which-key-mode beacon-mode modalka-mode helm-mode company-mode ivy-mode yas-minor-mode smartparens-mode)
  4510
  '(1 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((buffer-file-coding-system . emacs-mule-unix)))
```

Comment: Did you upgrade or modify your Emacs installation in the meantime? Are you sure the file isn't corrupted? Please post the complete error message, and if possible your `.emacs.desktop` (censored for anything private).

Comment: Thank you. There was no upgrade in the meantime. I can re-create this problem for any session... I've added an example of the .emacs.desktop file and specified the question (actually what happens on restart is that one single file is reopened - the last active buffer in the previous session, nothing else). `Desktop-read` gives the error which I included in full length now. I wonder if it can have something to do with the encoding of the .emacs.desktop file - I use utf-8 everywhere, but .emacs.desktop has emacs-mule-unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the comments, that encoding is fine (note that it's explicit in the desktop file's header, hence clearly intentional).

The seeming-gibberish is byte-compiled elisp, and we can see from the file path displayed that it's from `auto-capitalize.elc`.

I can infer from the full path that this is an ELPA package you got from MELPA, so I suspect you basically have a third-party library which doesn't play nicely with desktop.el.

I would try editing both instances of `auto-capitalize` out of the desktop file, and then attempting to read it again.

Comment: You got it! Editing the `auto-capitalize` files out of .emacs.desktop didn't help, but deactivating the whole auto-capitalize package did. I have no idea how is it conflicting with destkop-save, but I'm glad this got sorted out! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You might follow this up with the `auto-capitalize` package author -- they may well be keen to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the solution](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-04/msg00805.html)

Here is how I set it up in my config:

```
(use-package auto-capitalize
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-to-list 'auto-capitalize-words "http")
  (add-to-list 'desktop-minor-mode-handlers
               '(auto-capitalize . (lambda (desktop-buffer-locals)))))
```